# event is bound multiple times

Tags: jquery, events

I am calling this piece of code when I click on a button:

```
       divElement.find('#_bajarFactura').one('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (tooltipMenu)
                tooltipMenu.hide();

            alert('Se baja el archivo de la factura en lugar de verla en el navegador.');

            divElement.find('#_bajarFactura').off('click', '**');

            return false;
        });
```

divElement is a popup that is opened every time I click that button.

Notice I am calling "one" method... the problem is that even I am using that method, the handler is called multiple times after I click on the button several times.

I am trying to force the event to be unbound by using the "off" method call, but without success.

Any help, please?

EDIT: this is divElement:

```
<div id="tooltip_content">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a id="_bajarFactura" href="#" title="Bajar factura"><i class="sl-icon-cloud-download"></i>Bajar factura original</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a id="_verFactura" href="#" title="Ver archivo de la factura"><i class="sl-icon-doc"></i>Ver factura original</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a id="_verDetalle" href="#" title="Ver detalles de la factura"><i class="sl-icon-magnifier-add"></i>Ver Detalle</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a id="_reEnviar" href="#" title="Re-enviar factura a un e-mail"><i class="icon-Mail-Forward"></i>Re-enviar</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it. You said that `divElement` is opened when you click the button, but `#_bajarFactura` (I guess that is the button) is inside the `divElement`... Could you post a stripped out version of your HTML?

Comment: Are you recreating dynamically `#_bajarFactura`? Is it possible than the code that creates the event listener is called more than once?

Comment: No no no... #_bajarFactura is not the button..... it is just an <A> element inside the popup that is opened. I edited the question with divElement

Comment: If you're using an `id` as a selector you don't need to use `.find` just use the selector. `$("#_bajarFactura")`. Secondly, you're calling `e.preventDefault` which will  prevent the `.one` method from knowing whether or not it has been called once. Finally `.off("click", "**")` will remove all delegated events, but the `click` event isn't a delegated event. It's explicitly added to your element.

Comment: Ok. I think I see the problem. The js code that you posted is inside the event handler for that button right? So, you are creating a  event handler for `#_bajarFactura` every time you click on that button.

Comment: First, I need to use "find", because there are several copies of divElement inside the page. Second, if I don't use e.preventDefault, the page is redirected to the HREF pointed by the <A>. Third.... I talked you this is a button that calls that method to simplify the problem. It is in fact a tooltip that every time it shows the popup, calls that method. This has to be that way because I don't know what "divElement" is before hand. It is only known when the tooltip is shown.

Comment: @zfrisch - "e.preventDefault which will prevent the .one method from knowing whether or not it has been called once." What do you mean? You can add `e.preventDefault` and still the event handler will run just once.

Comment: @jstuardo  There should never be more than one element with the same `id` in a page. If you're not using the `href` then could you use a span tag with styling? It seems like these problems are going to compound.

Comment: @David You're right, my mistake.

Comment: @zfrisch I could change the id to be a css class, but I think the problem will be the same. Tooltip creates copies of the same divElement when it is attached to the element that opens the tooltip. Even no more than one id should exists in the page, this is not causing the problem, because I can assure that by using the "find" method, the correct <A> element binds the "click" event.

Comment: @zfrisch I am using the href to open a modal dialog when clicked on the link.

Comment: Everytime that you show the tooltip, `divElement.find('#_bajarFactura').one('click', ...` is executed, storing a new event hander. It will be there until you trigger it and it would accumulate to successive calls to `one()`. It is what I tried to say in my last comment.

Comment: I tried by using "divElement.find('#_bajarFactura').off('click', '**');" before the call to "on" but it did not work either.

Comment: Finally, and to stop fighting with this, I have used old JavaScript fashion.... I simply added "onclick="return fnVerFactura();"" directly in A tag and that's all.

Comment: As @zfrisch has told you, passing the special value `"**"` won't remove non-delegated events. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler attachment `one()` is quite intuitive. The event handler will run just once.

If it doesn't is because you set the event listener more than once.

```js
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  $('#_bajarFactura').one('click', function(event) {
    console.log('handler executed');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="_bajarFactura">Click me!</button>
```

Watch out how are you showing the tooltip.

You should call `$('#_bajarFactura').off('click');` when you close it.

**Note**: Don't use `('#_bajarFactura').off('click', '**')`. As *@zfrisch* has told you, it will remove just the delegated events. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/#entry-longdesc):

> To remove all delegated events from an element without removing non-delegated events, use the special value "**".